# Bash: examine stdin but forward it intact to another program?

Tags: linux, bash, stdin

There are many examples around here with bash using `while read line` to take in `stdin`

However I only want to examine the `stdin`, not destroy or modify it, and forward that intact, completely to another program (expecting stdin) on exit.

Is that possible? Is this a `tee` solution? Can it be done without `tee` ?

Note in this case the `stdin` may be rather large and/or contain binary so I don't want to read it into a string, I only need to examine the beginning of it.

Comment: What *exactly* do you need to do to the input? Does your script need to act on it or do you just want to see it yourself? If you need to actually see the data in real time then I think your only option is to read the data you need and then re-output everything else.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `tee` and process substitution (good job this is tagged [tag:bash]!):

Comment: something like `firstprog | while read -r line; do inspect "${line}"; echo "${line}"; done | secondprog`

Comment: Reading data from a stream inherently removes it from that stream.  If you want input data to be consumed by two different processes, then, either one must forward it to the other, or some third program -- such as `tee` -- must split the stream, forwarding it to both.  Note, however, that one output of `tee` always goes to a *file*, so you'll have to go to a bit more effort to convert that into input to a *process*.

Comment: @WalterA another catch is I cannot pipe directly to the secondprog because I may have to modify its command line args based on the stdin I am examining - complicated, I know!

Comment: @EtanReisner the size of stdin may be excessive to buffer in bash, I cannot output it in realtime because I may have to modify the command line of the program the stdin is being routed to - can I "push" data back into stdin after reading the first few lines out of it?

Comment: You don't need to buffer the whole thing (or really much of anything). Just `read` as much as you need then `cat | secondprog` or so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `coproc` and `group command` (`{}`) for this. I came up with the following:

```
coproc cat .profile  # our "firstprog"
exec 200<&${COPROC[0]}  # to keep it open after the first read

while read -r line; do
  firstline="$line"
  break
done <&200  # feed the loop from our new filedescriptor

{  # open group command to batch the output of the embedded commands
  echo FIRST LINE WAS: $firstline  # reprint the read line(s)
  cat <&200  # copy the rest...
} | sed 's:^:_ :g'  # our "secondprog" just to see things modified
```

`coproc` by default creates an array named `COPROC` holding the file descriptors for the stdin/stdout of the command executed by it. But after the first use (`read`) it would be closed, so you have to copy it (`<&`) to a dedicated one (`200`). After the loop, you have the `firstline` variable set and you can use it to parametrize the second command. Of course if you only care about the first line then don't use a loop. That is just for the sake of the example.
The other thing is that if you want to stream into the stdin of the second command then you have to batch the generated output together with a group command. This way you don't have to use tempfiles.

You can find out everything about these in `man bash`.

Answer (score 1):

When you must determine how to start secondprog after examining the output, you must wait for the firstprog to be finished. So you can let the examiner start the secondprog, using the input stored in a file.

```
firstprog | tee outfile | myfilter.sh
```

with some logic to make an optionlist (make a function like my_inspect)

```
optionlist=""
while read -r line; do 
   optionlist+=$(my_inspect "${line}")
done
secondprog ${optionlist} < outfile
rm outfile
```